# the development server returned response error code 500 - react native - ./configs/main

Tags: android, git, reactjs, react-native

I got this error when i tried to make `hello-world` sample:
`react-native init hello_world
cd hello_world
react-native run-android`

Even when I ran:
`npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
react-native-git-upgrade`
I got same error on `commend line console`.
[image]

I've searched and tried many solutions but it doesn't seem to work:
Example:
* `upgrade react-native`
* using watchman `watchman watch-del-all`
* remove `node_modules`
* clean cache `npm cache clean`or `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Operation: Window 8
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.44.2 ( tried 0.47.1 too )
Android: Simulator Nexus5X

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: you can try deleting babel-preset-react-native folder inside node_modules and then install older version 2.1.0 of this library. New version has some bug

Comment: do you mean `npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0 --save-dev`?

Comment: Yes, try doing that

Comment: work like charm. thank you

Comment: I am posting this as an answer, please accept and up vote so that it can help others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete `babel-preset-react-native` folder inside `node_modules` and then install older version 2.1.0 of this library with `npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0 --save-dev`.

Answer (score 3):

In case if someone is using react-native: 0.57.1 or the latest one,babel-preset-react-native has been replaced by metro-react-native-babel-preset. if you still get 500 error while connecting to the device do the below step and I guess things will be fine

```
npm add @babel/runtime
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the following:

```
react-native init Project
cd Project
npm uninstall react-native
npm install --save react-native@0.55.4
npm uninstall --save babel-preset-react-native
npm install --save babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it's about the react native version. I just install the new version of react native "0.59.2" then i downgrade to previous version to "0.55.2", and everything works fine.