# the development server returned response error code 500 on my emulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator, android-gradle-plugin

I am installing the react-native environment to start developing but when I run the command `react-native run-android`   I have this error.

> root@pc:~/l3/s2/DevMobMultipltm/Wakapp# `
>
> Scanning folders for symlinks in /root/l3/s2/DevMobMultipltm/Wakapp/node_modules (166ms)
> Starting JS server...
> Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
> Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
> :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> :app:checkDebugManifest
> :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee130Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore130Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco130Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline130Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase130Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3130Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0553Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareDebugDependencies
> :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
> :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
> :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
> :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
> :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:validateSigningDebug
> :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:installDebug
> 01:20:32 E/adb: adb server version (36) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
> 01:20:35 E/adb: * daemon started successfully
> Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Phone(AVD) - 6.0' for app:debug
> Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 12.012 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Running adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.wakapp/com.wakapp.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.wakapp/.MainActivity }

I think that is at the level of

> :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED

the mistake
On my emulator :
[the development server returned response error code 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXiaF.png)

someone to help me

Thank you in advance !!

NB: I am on Linux.

Comment: Try restarting your node server. Also close emulator and try again

Answer (score 0):

What stands out from the error message is the following line:
`adb server version (36) doesn't match this client (39); killing...`

Your issue seems like a duplicate of [ADB server version (36) doesn't match this client (39)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050370/adb-server-version-36-doesnt-match-this-client-39) and [adb server version doesn't match this client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092542/adb-server-version-doesnt-match-this-client)

Comment: Thanks for your help

But in my case the problem "adb server version (36) does not match this client (39) killing ...
"does not prevent to work.

this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733527/the-development-server-returned-response-error-code-500-react-native-confi/45737998] solved my problem. I delete the folder 'babel-preset-react-native' in 'node_module' in my project then always in the project I typed the command `npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0 --save-dev`
and it works.